# I get segmentation error with fscanf and fgets in accepting N string lines in C

Tags: c, string, struct, linked-list, polynomials

I have a struct for a polynomial with variables x, y, and z

```
struct Node
{
    float coeff;
    int powX;
    int powY;
    int powZ;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

I want to read `n` user inputs of polynomials in the form `powX` `powY` `powZ` `coeff`, I have an implementation with a `for` loop but it is giving me **segmentation errors**. What could be the problem?

```
void readPolynomial(struct Node** poly)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    *poly = temp;

    int terms;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &terms);
    getchar();

    char entry[200];
    char * splitter;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        fgets(entry, 200, stdin);
        
        splitter = strtok(entry," ");
        temp->powX = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powY = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powZ = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->coeff = atof(splitter);
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(i != terms-1)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my main function:

```
int main()
{
    struct Node* first = NULL;

    readPolynomial(&first);
    return 0;
}
```

For the polynomial `4x⁵y⁴z²`: `5 4 2 4`

Sample Input:

```
3
5 4 2 4
1 6 0 -7
1 0 1 9
```

**FULL CODE FUNCTION: Get the sum of two polynomials, print in canonical order**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

struct Node
{
    float coeff;
    int powX;
    int powY;
    int powZ;
    struct Node* next;
};


void readPolynomial(struct Node** poly)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    *poly = temp;

    int terms;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &terms);
    getchar();

    char entry[200];
    char *splitter;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        fgets(entry, 200, stdin);
        splitter = strtok(entry," ");
        temp->powX = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powY = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powZ = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->coeff = atof(splitter);
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(i != terms-1)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int degree(struct Node *term) {
    return (term->powX*pow(10, 2)) + (term->powY*pow(10, 1)) + (term->powZ*pow(10, 0));
}

int termCount(struct Node* poly)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(poly != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        poly = poly->next;
    }
    return count;
}

void displayPolynomial(struct Node* poly)
{
    int c = termCount(poly);
    struct Node *temp1, *t, *temp2;
    int tempX, tempY, tempZ, tempCoeff;
    for(int i = c-2; i>= 0; i--)
    {
        temp1 = poly;
        temp2 = temp1->next;
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if(degree(temp1) < degree(temp2))
            {
                tempX = temp1->powX;
                tempY = temp1->powY;
                tempZ = temp1->powZ;
                tempCoeff = temp1->coeff;

                temp1->powX = temp2->powX;
                temp1->powY = temp2->powY;
                temp1->powZ = temp2->powZ;
                temp1->coeff = temp2->coeff;

                temp2->powX = tempX;
                temp2->powY = tempY;
                temp2->powZ = tempZ;
                temp2->coeff = tempCoeff;
            }
            temp1 = temp2;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
    t = poly;
    while(t != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d %.3f\n", t->powX, t->powY, t->powZ, t->coeff);
        t = t->next;
    }
}

void addPolynomials(struct Node** result, struct Node* first, struct Node* second)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->next = NULL;
    *result = temp;
    while(first && second)
    {
        if(((first->powX*pow(10, 2)) + (first->powY*pow(10, 1)) + (first->powZ*pow(10, 0))) < (((second->powX*pow(10, 2)) + (second->powY*pow(10, 1)) + (second->powZ*pow(10, 0)))))
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;

        }
        else if(((first->powX*pow(10, 2)) + (first->powY*pow(10, 1)) + (first->powZ*pow(10, 0))) > (((second->powX*pow(10, 2)) + (second->powY*pow(10, 1)) + (second->powZ*pow(10, 0)))))
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff + second->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
            second = second->next;
        }
        if(first && second)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    while(first || second)
    {
        temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(second)
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;
        }

        else if(first)
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* first = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* result = NULL;

    readPolynomial(&first);
    readPolynomial(&second);
    addPolynomials(&result, first, second);
    displayPolynomial(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

```
3
1 6 0 -7
0 7 0 -6
7 0 0 1
5
1 0 1 9
0 7 0 -2
5 3 2 4
1 2 3 4
1 3 0 3
```

Sample Output:

```
7 0 0 1.000
5 3 2 4.000
1 6 0 -7.000
1 3 0 3.000
1 2 3 4.000
1 0 1 9.000
0 7 0 -8.000
```

Comment: My guess is `strtok` is returning NULL and `atoi(NULL)` is the problem.  Validate your input.

Comment: The code works for me (I wouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()`). Are you sure the error isn't in `main()` or some other function that uses `first`? Surely you do not just `readPolynomial()` and quit...

Comment: Note that the problem could simply be trailing spaces at the end of the first line of input.  Validate the input.  Always.

Comment: The cast to the return value of `malloc()` silences the diagnostic from the compiler which may hide an error. Did you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @pmg The actual function of the full code is to get the sum of two polynomials. I updated my post since you mentioned that the partial codes are working fine, the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: you are not including `<string.h>` isn't strtok there?

Comment: Oh riiight I missed the string library. Thank you @myradio! All is well now.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings from the compiler? compile with full warnings (in gcc would be `-Wall -Wextra`)

Comment: I do have the warnings but it did not mention adding any other library.  Anyway, code works for most cases and gives wrong output for some. Problem's most likely with my algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with full warnings (in gcc would be `-Wall -Wextra`).

In this case you will see that you are not including `<string.h>`, C allows an implicit declaration (`int (*)()`), but the behaviour is not what you want.

add the following to your code,

```
#include <string.h>
```